# Automatic login when powered on

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I would like to know how can I

```
1. power on a remote computer 
2. automatically log in (that client does have username and password to log in) with a given pair of username and password
```

I finish the first and wonder if the second is possible ? Any help is appreciated. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the registry to auto login a computer. The key you need is:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`

Change `AutoAdminLogon` to `1`.

Set `DefaultUserName` and `DefaultPassword` to the accounts username and password.

If the values don't exist just create them. Usually `AutoAdminLogon` and `DefaultUserName` are already there but you may have to create `DefaultPassword`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @solomon Yep, I've used it on Windows XP and above and it works great.

Comment: On windows 7, the LSA store is used to store an encrypted version of the password. So the method of setting the registry keys will work the first time only, thereafter the secure store will be used. Take a look at this link for setting a secure default password [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268214/how-to-auto-login-to-windows-account)

Comment: @Mahen I think that the password remains unencrypted in the values list. So basically anyone using the computer could access the value. Is there a way to put the password to LSA without `netplwiz` or Sysinternals `Autologon` tool?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not power on a turned off system. You may need it to be in stand by state or something like that. If it is turned off, you will need a hardware part to turn it on.
If you want to remotely login in to the system, it depends on the OS of that system. what is it ?

Comment: On the second line the OP says they have managed to power it on already.

Answer (score 0):

If alt-ctrl-del is required at user login i dont think it can be automated. it requires human presence.